# Enable Activity Tracking with ETW/WAD in Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, etw, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to get activity tracking enabled using ETW/WAD with Service Fabric and would just like some clarification on what is necessary.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2015/09/14/exploring-eventsource-activity-correlation-and-causation-features/

This article & the supplied .docx seem to suggest that all that is necessary is suffixing your function name with Start / Stop and running .net 4.6. I'm doing both of these things but do not seem to be having any joy.

I've also tried using Start / Stop opcodes, but have found the same issues there - the activity Id in WAD is always all 0s and the opcodename field is empty.

Edit - I'm using self describing. Using the manifest style the opcodenames will be populated, but the activityId still will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered here: [Service Fabric ETW Logs are always incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122617/service-fabric-etw-logs-are-always-incomplete)

In summary - WAD & VS diagnostics data viewer do not currently support this. For diagnostics there is a release in the works which will correct it. No ETA for WAD.